# yii2start - trouble in seting document root on local web server

Tags: yii2, document-root

I've installed the **yii2start** (https://github.com/vova07/yii2-start) on my localhost and on step 8 there's this instruction to **set documents root of web server**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.yii2-start.domain # You need to change it to your own domain  
    ServerAlias yii2-start.domain # You need to change it to your own domain  
    DocumentRoot /my/path/to/yii2-start # You need to change it to your own path  
    <Directory /my/path/to/yii2-start> # You need to change it to your own path  
        AllowOverride All  
    </Directory>  
</VirtualHost>
```

and replaced the values according to my localhost application

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName http://localhost/yii2start/yii2-start  
    ServerAlias http://localhost/yii2start/yii2-start  
    DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/yii2start/yii2-start  
    <Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/yii2start/yii2-start>  
        AllowOverride All  
    </Directory>  
</VirtualHost>
```

Now when I type **localhost** instead of the **xampp default page** I'm getting the **yii2start application**, and when I'm trying to acess the others websites in **xampp/htdocs/** for example **localhost/webapp** I get **404 error**.

What should change in order to have my others projects in htdocs to appear and my yii2start website to????

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You do not need step 8, if you remove the virtual host it should all still work ok just like the other websites so with the full path. I am not sure you can have your websites work with virtual hosts and without in the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yii2-start  
    ServerAlias yii2-start  
    DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/yii2start/yii2-start  
    <Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/yii2start/yii2-start>  
        AllowOverride All  
    </Directory>  
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart server. And open in browser http:://yii2-start.